# Error while trying to use simple_form following a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

```
Rails 6
simple_form
bootstrap 4
```

I have a table, in my views/books/index.htmlslim, that I would like to add a simple_form to, as follows:

```
table.table.table-striped
  thead
    tr
      th Name
  tbody
    - @books.each do |book|
      tr
        td = book.name

= simple_form_for(@book) do |f|
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :book_name

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

I am, however, getting an error message, telling me:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass):
```

Assuming because this is the Index view. How do I fix this?

## Edit:

To clarify, when I submit the form, I want it to go to the book new controller action, not the index action, so I am looking for the equivalent of:

```
= form_with url: new_book_url do |f|
```

Comment: What's `@book`? I suspect you don't set it in your `index` action, so it's `nil` and that's why you get this error.

Comment: If you set `@book` as I showed you, clicking on the submit button would direct you to `create` action actually, which is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `@book` instance variable in your `index` action:

```
def index
  @book = Book.new
  # rest of the code, setting @books etc.
end
```

Comment: What I really want, is to send the form to the book new controller action